# Variable args SFINAE default constructor works in clang, but fails in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Anyone know if this code is bad or if VS has a bug or if Clang is permissive?

I think my constructor should accept no parameters and pass the enable_if check - but somewhere VS is saying "no".

Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 gives the following error:

```
source_file.cpp(##): error C2512: 'Foo::Foo': no appropriate default constructor available
```

clang live: http://rextester.com/VWAI2954

VS live with error: http://rextester.com/PTDSS2853

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;


template <bool... b> struct static_all_of;

// If the first parameter is true, look at the rest of the list
template <bool... tail>
struct static_all_of<true, tail...> : static_all_of<tail...> {};

// if any parameter is false, return false
template <bool... tail>
struct static_all_of<false, tail...> : std::false_type {};

// If there are no parameters left, no false was found so return true
template <> struct static_all_of<> : std::true_type {};



struct Bar{};

struct Foo {

 template <class... Things,
  std::enable_if_t<static_all_of<std::is_base_of<Bar, std::remove_pointer_t<Things>>::value...>::value, int> = 0>
   Foo(Things... stuff){}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;  
}
```

Comment: Turns out it's the std::remove_pointer_t bit.. if I switch it to `typename std::remove_pointer<..>::type` then it works fine.

Comment: At this point maybe if anyone could point out a specific VS bug or some docs saying that something I'm doing isn't compatible with VS, that woul dbe great.

Comment: Compiles without issues with gcc 5.3.1

Comment: @xaxxon https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx lists SFINAE in general as "not" supported, even in version 2015. ... not a "specific bug", but that's how it is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for checking that.

Comment: @deviantfan If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.   Or if you don't, I will tomorrow

Comment: @xaxxon I would feel bad for earning reputation just from that :) Maybe I have time later to explain why it is ok with the standard, but if not, feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: @deviantfan Well, I think it's helpful for someone coming across a similar error while porting to windows to learn about fundamental, long-standing parts of modern c++ that simply aren't expected to work in visual studio - it was quite helpful for me to reset my expectations.

Comment: There are some Visual C++ bugs related to `using` (template aliases). SFINAE in general works just fine. Tip: instead of the current approach with specific TMP code for each boolean operation, just define a single template that *counts* the number of `true` values.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf not sure th ebest way to do that.. just recursive inheritence where your count is your parent's count + 1 if your value is true?

Comment: @deviantfan "Expression SFINAE" and SFINAE are completely different beasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deviantfan said - there's actually no claim by MS that Visual Studio 2015 actually has proper SFINAE support at all, so this wouldn't appear to be a specific bug, just VS2015 not being C++11 compliant.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx